# Specific Orientation Background

Tags: ipad, ios6, orientation

Here my code for specifying the background in ipad iOS6,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 1024)
    {
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"homeipad.png"]];
    }
    else if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 768)
    {
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"landscapipad.png"]];
    }
}
```

its not changing depends on orientation?I have included

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
     return YES;
}
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

How to allocate specific background image for corresponding orientation in ipad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember `viewDidLoad` is called only when you make a new `UIViewController` object in the memory and you push/present that controller object.

the method name `viewDidLoad` defines that your viewcontroller view is loaded. Now you can perform the all initialization tasks here.

**Answer to your question.**

The following UIVIewController's delegate methods will help you in this. These methods are called every time when device changes its orientation.

```
// Called before interface rotation 
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;

// Called after interface rotation
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation;
```

One more thing, rather than comparing screen height , you can check the current orientation from the above two methods.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
{
    if( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation))
    {
        // Your code goes here for landscape orientation
    }
    else
    {
        // Your code goes here for portrait orientation
    }
}
```